# How do I return a filename for os.path as a string?

Tags: python-3.x, path, operating-system, filenames

I am iterating through a list of files. For each file I want to assign the name of the file to a variable as type string. I want to use the filename string in print statements, to name output files, and for log entries.

I've tried getting the filename and then using the str() function.

```
def source_data():
    # Create path and file listing for csv exports in landing zone
    csv_dir = 'C:\\Path\\to\\data\\nets'
    file_list = list(os.scandir(csv_dir))
    csv_file_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.path.endswith('.csv'), 
    file_list))
return csv_file_list  

for f in csv_file_list:
    with open(file=f, mode='r', newline='') as csvfile:
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[1])[0]

....process loop

def net_file(n_string, filename):
    with open(file=filename + '.txt', mode='w') as txtfile:
        print(n_string, file=txtfile)
    print('Finished Processing.... {} Subnets...'.format(filename))
```

## When I run the script, I get this error...

```
with open(file=filename + '.txt', mode='w') as txtfile:
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: you're not providing a [mcve] so I can't be sure but it looks like you're not using the filename correctly, as a long shot, try `filename[0]`

Comment: Using the REPL I create the filename var with the same commands above.

So in the with open statement, I looked at the variables:
>>> txtfile
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='JV_On net_GER_AIS_7317.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>

and

>>> print(txtfile.name)
JV_On net_GER_AIS_7317.txt

Giving me what I want... so I'm still not sure why it wouldn't work. Sorry, I can't expose all of the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was returning the correct text filename to the variable assignment. I had scoping problems within my script which, when corrected, fixed the issue.